# Firebase realtime database and authentication library version incompatibility

Tags: java, android, firebase

IMPORTANT NOTE: 
I read this [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) but none of those answers solved my problem. Same with [Android Build execution failed due to incompatible library versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919110/android-build-execution-failed-due-to-incompatible-library-versions?rq=1).

I want to connect my app to firebase realtime database and add an authentication with phone number and email. When I added the build.gradle dependencies in my app module for the realtime database there were no issues, but when I add the authentication dependencies i get the following message: 
[error_message_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjG1w.png)
The problem is that I already added those libraries in the same version (i put them all in 15.0.0), and yet even after sync i get the same message. 
What can I do to solve that problem ? 
Here is my gradle: (the commented part is another method found on firebase that i tried but it didn't work either)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "finalproject.mad.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'

    /*implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0"


    implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"

    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"*/

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EDIT: Updating Android Studio fixed my problem

Comment: make sure you're using the latest version of Android Studio (`Android Studio -> Check for updates..`)

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya i read what you wrote but here it was not an exception so there were no details, it was just a message. But next time i'll write it down in addition to the picture (here i was afraid it would make the post too long). Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Signo updating Android Studio work, i was using version 3.0.1 and now it works with the new version. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase updated the dependencies versions, use the following:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but when i use this i still get the same problem, as i'm using different versions. Do i just ignore the issue ?

Comment: if i add      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:3.3.0' before the 2 lines you wrote, I get the error "All firebase libraries must be either above or under 14.0.0". Yet i'm using versions 15.0.0 and 15.1.0 ...

Comment: add it in the top level gradle file

Comment: i did that and now i'm back to the first error i had ("All gms/firebase libraries lust be the exact same version specification")